# Update cell background color for google spreadsheet using python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I wanna use google api to update the background color of a cell in a spreadsheet with `batchupdate` function.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate
what should my request be like if to update the cell `sheet1!A1` with the value `value` and background color `red`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- You want to change the background color of the cell "A1" in the sheet name of "Sheet1" on Google Spreadsheet to red using the method of batchUpdate of Sheets API.
- You want to achieve this using google-api-python-client with python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Sample script:

```
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set Spreadsheet ID
sheetId = "###"  # Please set sheet ID.

body = {
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateCells": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 1,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 1
        },
        "rows": [
          {
            "values": [
              {
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                  "backgroundColor": {
                    "red": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor"
      }
    }
  ]
}
res = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, body=body).execute()
```

#### Note:

- In this case, the range is required to be written with [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange).

  - `startRowIndex: 0, endRowIndex: 1m startColumnIndex: 0, endColumnIndex: 1` means the cell "A1".

#### References:

- [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)
- [CellFormat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellFormat)
- [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange)
- [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)

  - About the script for authorizing, you can see it at Python Quickstart.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple basic format for changing background color of the cell :

```
worksheet.format("A2:B2", {
    "backgroundColor": {
      "red": 0.0,
      "green": 0.0,
      "blue": 0.0
    }
```

Comment: +1 While it doesn't match the expectation expressed in the actual posting ("...using batchupdate..."), but it works.