# How to filter data with googlespreadsheets api by color?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I want to parse data from my google spreadsheets, but I need a filter by background color. (especially yellow and blue)

The part of the code and the part of google spreadsheet are shown.

[image: code]
[image: spreadsheet]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The background colour corerponds to the field `sheets/data/rowData/values/effectiveFormat/backgroundColor` of the method [Spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

The structure of the corresponding JSON object looks like

```
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "effectiveFormat": {
                    "backgroundColor": {
                      "red": 1,
                      "green": 1,
                      "blue": 1
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "effectiveFormat": {
                    "backgroundColor": {
                      "red": 1
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "effectiveFormat": {
                    "backgroundColor": {
                      "green": 1
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "effectiveFormat": {
                    "backgroundColor": {
                      "red": 1,
                      "green": 1,
                      "blue": 1
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "effectiveFormat": {
                    "backgroundColor": {
                      "red": 1,
                      "green": 1,
                      "blue": 1
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now it is up to you to implement loops and conditional statements to decide what you want to do with your data as a function of the background color.

Have a look at [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59727637/11599789) for updating background colors which should be useful to you for implementing the JSON structure into Python code.

Comment: Actually I wanted to get information and filter it by color, same as I was doing with spreadsheets.values.get. I don't know whether it is possible or not. I would highly appreciate it if you help me.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no built-in option to filter values by background color of the cell, so you'll need to build your filter function manually.

Comment: I just wonder how I am supposed to get backgroundcolor from this JSON, is there any library which can help me with that?

Comment: In Python you'd need to specify `fields ='sheets(data(rowData(values(effectiveFormat/backgroundColor))))'`

Comment: I finally got it working, appreciate your help. Many thanks!