# Update Google spreadsheet cell (python)

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I read (quite) similar posts like this but I'm not able to fix my problem, and google documentation is not 100% useful since they don't provide real examples.

The thing is I'm facing a problem with google sheets. What I'm trying to do is to update cells in a google sheet. Basically, I read a sheet and if a specific column doesn't have a specific word/state, I do an automation with selenium (I don't show you this step since it's not important), and once is done, I write the word 'OK' in a column in my Google sheet. This column is empty or with the word 'OK' wrote on it. I'm able to read the sheet and do the automation, but I get an error when trying to update the sheet.

This is my code (basically is Google's code):

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
SPREADSHEET_ID = '1cuT66AD3TBQ-1IWCisB0pUPzlw-iOuuU7vO2TqRj3bQ' #control seguimiento robot
WORKSHEET_NAME = 'PRUEBAS DAVID cambio estado TAS'

async def leerGoogleSheet():
    creds = None
   
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            # pass
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'client_secret.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range=WORKSHEET_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    print('result: ' + str(result))
    print('range: ' + str(range))

    print('values: ' + str(result['values']))
   
    print('WO: ' + str(result['values'][1][1]))
   
    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
        print(traceback)
    else:
       
        losDatos = []
       
        for row in range(1, len(values)):
            # print('num_fila:' +str(num_fila))
        
            if 'TAS' in values[row][0]:
                if values[row][11] == 'Pendiente':
                    try:
                        if values[row][12]:
                            print('ya tiene valor OK')
                            pass
                    except:
                        print('Hay TAS')
                        datos = []
                        datos.append(values[row][0]) #tas
                        datos.append(values[row][1]) #wo
                        datos.append(row)

                        losDatos.append(datos)
                        await escribirEnSheet(service, row)

            else:
                print('No hay TAS')

        print(losDatos)


    #CAMBIAR ESTADO

    
async def escribirEnSheet(service, row):
    range_ = 'M'+str(row) 
        
    value_input_option = 'RAW'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

    values = ['OK']
    value_range_body = {'values': values,
    'majorDimension' : 'COLUMNS'}

    print('voy a hacer la request para escribir')
   
    request = service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=range_, valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=value_range_body)
    response = request.execute()
    print('ya he escrito')
```

And this is the error I got:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1cuT66AD3TBQ-1IWCisB0pUPzlw-iOuuU7vO2TqRj3bQ/values/M2?valueInputOption=RAW&alt=
json returned "Invalid value at 'data.values' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "OK"". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'f
ield': 'data.values', 'description': 'Invalid value at \'data.values\' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "OK"'}]}]">
```

The error is in this line,

```
value_range_body = {'values': values,
    'majorDimension' : 'COLUMNS'}
```

tried different 'configurations' don't know how to fix it, it looks fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification?

In this case, please use 2 dimensional array for `values`. I think that the reason of your error message is due to this. So please modify as follows ans test it again.

#### From:

```
values = ['OK']
```

#### To:

```
values = [['OK']]
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: One last question @Tanaike ... How could I add a background color in this example? I've seen this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59727373/update-cell-background-color-for-google-spreadsheet-using-python] and I understand I have to add the background into my values, but how is the proper way to do this?

Comment: @dtamab Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: You are right @Tanaike. I've posted a question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62632484/add-background-color-to-cell-google-sheet-python Thanks!