# Add background color to cell Google sheet (python)

Tags: python, google-sheets, background-color, google-sheets-api

related to this question ([Update Google spreadsheet cell (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62534372/update-google-spreadsheet-cell-python/62544860?noredirect=1#comment110694383_62544860)), I'd like to know how to change the background color of a cell (or a full row) in the link example.

This is the part of my code where I update the sheet. I pass the service and the row. It worked when I only wrote 'OK' in a single cell with the 'values' variable, but not with the modifications for the background of the row:

```
SPREADSHEET_ID = '###'
WORKSHEET_NAME = 'Name of the sheet'

async def escribirEnSheet(service, row):
    # print('voy a escribir en celda ' + str(range_))
    # range_ = 'M'+str(row)  # TODO: Update placeholder value.
    row += 1
    range_ = WORKSHEET_NAME + "!M" + str(row)
    print('voy a escribir en celda: ' + str(range_))

#values = [['OK']]

sheetObj = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, fields='sheets(properties(sheetId,title))').execute()
sheet_id = ""
for sheet in sheetObj['sheets']:
    if sheet['properties']['title'] == WORKSHEET_NAME:
        sheet_id = sheet['properties']['sheetId']
        break


batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "updateCells": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                    "startRowIndex": row,
                    "endRowIndex": row+1,
                    "startColumnIndex": 12,
                    "endColumnIndex": 12
                },
                "rows": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "userEnteredValue": {
                                    "stringValue": "OK"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "fields": "userEnteredValue"
            }
        },
        {
            "repeatCell": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": WORKSHEET_NAME,
                    "startRowIndex": row,
                    "endRowIndex": row+1,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                },
                "cell": {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                        "backgroundColor": {
                            "red": 0,
                            "green": 1,
                            "blue": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor"
            }
        }
    ]
}

value_input_option = 'RAW'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.


try:
    print('voy a hacer la request para escribir')
    
    request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, body=batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body)
    response = request.execute()
    time.sleep(1)
    print('ya he escrito')
    
    print(response)
except:
    print('algo ha ocurrido al escribir en la sheet')
    traceback.print_exc()
    pass
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to modify the background color of a cell or a row using googleapis with python.

For this, how about this answer? In this answer, the method of "spreadsheets.batchUpdate" in Sheets API is used. At the batchUpdate method, the GridRange is used as the range. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange)

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the background color of a cell is modified.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, the background color of the cell "A1" of the sheet of `sheet_id` is modified to red.

```
SPREADSHEET_ID = '###'  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_id = '###'  # Please set the sheet ID.

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "repeatCell": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 1,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                    "endColumnIndex": 1
                },
                "cell": {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                        "backgroundColor": {
                            "red": 1,
                            "green": 0,
                            "blue": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor"
            }
        }
    ]
}

request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, body=batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body)
res = request.execute()
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the background color of a row is modified.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, the background color of the 1st row of the sheet of `sheet_id` is modified to red.

```
SPREADSHEET_ID = '###'  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_id = '###'  # Please set the sheet ID.

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "repeatCell": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 1,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                },
                "cell": {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                        "backgroundColor": {
                            "red": 1,
                            "green": 0,
                            "blue": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor"
            }
        }
    ]
}

request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, body=batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body)
res = request.execute()
```

- In this case, `endColumnIndex` is removed from the pattern 1. By this, a row is used.

### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)

## Added1:

When you want to put a value to a cell and modify the background color of the row, how about the following sample script? In this case, the request for putting a value is added to the requests for the batchUpdate.

And also, you want to retrieve the sheet ID from the sheet name. About this, I added the following script.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, a value of "sample" is put to the cell "A1" and the background color of the 1st row is modified to red.

```
SPREADSHEET_ID = '###'  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'  # Please set the sheet name.

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheetObj = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, fields='sheets(properties(sheetId,title))').execute()
sheet_id = ""
for sheet in sheetObj['sheets']:
    if sheet['properties']['title'] == sheet_name:
        sheet_id = sheet['properties']['sheetId']
        break

batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "updateCells": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 1,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                    "endColumnIndex": 1
                },
                "rows": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "userEnteredValue": {
                                    "stringValue": "sample"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "fields": "userEnteredValue"
            }
        },
        {
            "repeatCell": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 1,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                },
                "cell": {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                        "backgroundColor": {
                            "red": 1,
                            "green": 0,
                            "blue": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor"
            }
        }
    ]
}

request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, body=batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body)
res = request.execute()
```

## Added2:

Your script has several modification points:

#### Modification points:

- At `updateCells`, if you want to put the value of `OK` to the column "L", please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      "startColumnIndex": 12,
      "endColumnIndex": 12
    ```
  - To

    ```
      "startColumnIndex": 11,
      "endColumnIndex": 12
    ```
  - When you want to put to the column "M", please modify `"startColumnIndex": 12,endColumnIndex": 13`.
- At `repeatCell`, `WORKSHEET_NAME` is used for the sheet ID. Please modify to `"sheetId": sheet_id,`.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike. And what about if I want to write in a single cell and change the background of that full row?

Comment: @dtamab Thank you for replying. For your additional request, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your additional request, I apologize.

Comment: I got an error with the sheet_id, I'm give the name of the sheet but it seems it has to be an integer, is that right? Is it possible to pass the name instead of the index?

Comment: @dtamab Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I updated the additional script for retrieving the sheet ID from the sheet name. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I got this error: googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1cuT66AD3TBQ-1IWCisB0pUPzlw-iOuuU7vO2TqRj3bQ:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid value at 'requests[1].repeat_cell.range.sheet_id' (TYPE_INT32), "PRUEBAS DAVID cambio estado TAS"". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'requests[1].repeat_cell.range.sheet_id', 'description': 'Invalid value at \'requests[1].repeat_cell.range.sheet_id\' (TYPE_INT32), "PRUEBAS DAVID cambio estado TAS"'}]}]">

Comment: I also modified this part of the code, since I want to write on the cells at column M, and change the row background:

This for writing the cell: "startRowIndex": row,
                        "endRowIndex": row+1,
                        "startColumnIndex": 12,
                        "endColumnIndex": 12

And this for the background "repeatCell": {
                    "range": {
                        "sheetId": WORKSHEET_NAME,
                        "startRowIndex": row,
                        "endRowIndex": row+1,
                        "startColumnIndex": 0,

Comment: @dtamab Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue. Because in my environment, I can confirm the above sample scripts worked. I apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand about your current issue, can you provide your current script for replicate your situation? If you can do, please add it to your question. By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: I added my code (the important part of it). Thanks for your help and dedication ;)

Comment: @dtamab Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Your script has the modification points for working. So I added the modification points for your script. Could you please confirm it?